# How can I validate HTML markup with javascript, and then show a preview of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to develop and build a forum. I have got quite far,  but there is now a problem.

I am allowing users to choose from some HTML tags when they post threads or replies,
these include: **<br>**, **<br />**, **<a>**, **<b>**, **<i>**, **<u>**, **<code>**, **<span>** and **<p>**

If the user types one of these into the contenteditable div element, how can I validate and show a preview of it as stackoverflow does? (but not as advanced)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be:

1. Capture key up
2. Read the text in textbox
3. Append what you have read to the DOM (for example the div that will contain the preview of the text)

You can use jquery to capture the events and append to the DOM:
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/
http://api.jquery.com/append/